# How to combine two array of objects into one array based on key match values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

My first array called feeds:

```
[
   {
      _id: '5b8906e81248270685399a9a',
      name: 'fin24',
      state: 'OK',
      status: true,
    },
   { 
      _id: '5b8907031248270685399a9b',
      name: 'news24',
      state: 'OK',
      status: true,
  } 
]
```

My second Array called feedArticlesCount:

```
feedArticlesCount: [ 
  { _id: 5b8907031248270685399a9b,
    pending: 21,
    approved: 1,
    active: 21,
    inactive: 1 },
  { _id: 5b8906e81248270685399a9a,
    pending: 20,
    approved: 0,
    active: 20,
    inactive: 0 },
  { _id: 5b8664c26d90b107d0952cbe,
    pending: 62,
    approved: 8,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 70 },
  { _id: 5b865bf28152610775987d67,
    pending: 111,
    approved: 30,
    active: 0,
    inactive: 141 } 
]
```

I want to combine these both two arrays into one based on matching _id value, if _id not exist in first array i want to skip that.

My Expected output:

```
[
   {
      _id: '5b8906e81248270685399a9a',
      name: 'fin24',
      state: 'OK',
      status: true,
      pending: 20,
      approved: 0,
      active: 20,
      inactive: 0 
    },
   { 
      _id: '5b8907031248270685399a9b',
      name: 'news24',
      state: 'OK',
      status: true,
      pending: 21,
      approved: 1,
      active: 21,
      inactive: 1 
  } 
]
```

I tried with forEach and reduce method, but its not working correctly

Here i tried:

```
let result = [];
feeds.forEach((itm, i) => {
  result.push(Object.assign({}, itm, feedArticlesCount[i]));
});

console.log(result);
```

This is working but my name key is storing in wrong _id place.

Comment: by id in wrong place do you mean not first ? I can't see the problem with that

Comment: @jonatjano http://jsbin.com/wufiravefu/edit?js,output check this

Comment: name is getting in wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's the *second* array that contains items that don't exist in the first array, you can `.map` by the first array instead, and `.find` the matching object in the second array:

```js
const arr=[{_id:'5b8906e81248270685399a9a',name:'fin24',state:'OK',status:!0,},{_id:'5b8907031248270685399a9b',name:'news24',state:'OK',status:!0,}];
const feedArticlesCount=[{_id:'5b8907031248270685399a9b',pending:21,approved:1,active:21,inactive:1},{_id:'5b8906e81248270685399a9a',pending:20,approved:0,active:20,inactive:0},{_id:'5b8664c26d90b107d0952cbe',pending:62,approved:8,active:0,inactive:70},{_id:'5b865bf28152610775987d67',pending:111,approved:30,active:0,inactive:141}]

console.log(arr.map(
  ({ _id, ...rest }) => ({ _id, ...rest, ...feedArticlesCount.find((item) => item._id === _id) })
));
```

For less complexity, you can transform the `feedArticlesCount` array into an object indexed by `_id` first (`O(N)` rather than a nested `.find`'s `O(N^2)`):

```js
const arr=[{_id:'5b8906e81248270685399a9a',name:'fin24',state:'OK',status:!0,},{_id:'5b8907031248270685399a9b',name:'news24',state:'OK',status:!0,}];
const feedArticlesCount=[{_id:'5b8907031248270685399a9b',pending:21,approved:1,active:21,inactive:1},{_id:'5b8906e81248270685399a9a',pending:20,approved:0,active:20,inactive:0},{_id:'5b8664c26d90b107d0952cbe',pending:62,approved:8,active:0,inactive:70},{_id:'5b865bf28152610775987d67',pending:111,approved:30,active:0,inactive:141}]

const articlesById = feedArticlesCount.reduce((a, { _id, ...rest }) => {
  a[_id] = rest;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(arr.map(
  ({ _id, ...rest }) => ({ _id, ...rest, ...articlesById[_id] })
));
```